# How to remove options tab in window.open when we open PDF / any file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have used window.open() of JavaScript function to display a PDF/an image. What is my question is I don't want to show options tab for user. Otherwise if possible I want to hide the 'download' and 'print' option from the window.open tab.
[image]

Comment: This is controlled by the browser/PDF viewer. There's nothing you can do to style the bar that's shown.

Comment: If I want to remove that print or download options, is there any script.?

Comment: No. When you're looking at a PDF in browser it's using the PDF viewer. No JS is loaded at that point.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done via code. This is a PDF preview. Not an **HTML** page. The only way you can remove the icons from showing i.e. print & download, is to edit Viewing PDFs and viewing preferences

https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/viewing-pdfs-viewing-preferences.html

Comment: I would like to do it using javascript or jquery is there any possibility..?